# Do doorways count as corners regarding tactical movement?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, terrain

You can't move diagonally past a corner. Does moving through a doorway on the battlemat count as a corner? I.e., I can't move diagonally through a doorway?

```
----------
|A1|A2|A3|
|B1|B2|B3|
|==|C2|==|
|D1|D2|D3|
```

D1 and B1 have a wall between them and D3 and B3. Could I move diagonally from D1 into C2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The walls around the door still count as corners, so page 147 of the PHB still stands:

> You can’t move diagonally past a corner (even by taking a 5-foot step).

If it was a double door, you could move diagonally so long as you didn't move through a corner.

```
|A1|A2|A3|A4|
|B1|B2|B3|B4|
|==|C2|C3|==|
|D1|D2|D3|D4|
```

Moving from D3 or B3 into C2 is legal as is moving from D2 or B2 into C3 (And vice versa for all), but moving from D1 to C2 is not as you're crossing the corner in C1.